# How does C# know what type the literal is?

Tags: c#

Consider this code:

```
double i = 0xF0000000;
Console.WriteLine(0xF0000000.GetType());
Console.WriteLine(i.GetType());
```

Why C# prints `System.UInt32` for first one and `System.Double` for the second one?

Is that because, the compiler by default infers a literal to be of type `var`?

Comment: There is no type `var`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In this line:

```
double i = 0xF0000000;
```

the *literal* is of type `uint`, but it's being implicitly converted to a `double`. When you call `i.GetType()` that would *always* print `System.Double`, because the variable is of type `double`... the *only* kind of value it can hold is a `double`.

Note that this conversion to `double` means you can lose precision, if you start off with a `long` or `ulong`. For example:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        long x = 123456789012345678;
        double y = 123456789012345678;
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("n"));
        Console.WriteLine(y.ToString("n"));
    }
}
```

prints

```
123,456,789,012,345,678.00
123,456,789,012,346,000.00
```

Note how the final few digits are lost in the `double`, because the implicit conversion from `long` to `double` can lose precision. (Both have 64 bits available, but in `double` only some of those bits are used for the mantissa.)

It's not a problem for `int` or `uint` literals, but it's worth being aware that the conversion is happening.

Answer (score 12):

According to [Integer Literals (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx) the type of an integer literal depends on the value, and its suffix.

> - If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: int, uint, long, ulong.
> - If the literal is suffixed by U or u, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: uint, ulong.
> - If the literal is suffixed by L or l, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: long, ulong.
> - If the literal is suffixed by UL, Ul, uL, ul, LU, Lu, lU, or lu, it is of type ulong.

0xF0000000 has no suffix, so it has **the first type that can represent it** (int, uint, long, ulong)

- int is 32-bit signed: 0xF0000000 is just outside it's range for positive values - next...
- uint is 32-bit unsigned: 0xF0000000 is within it's range - OK.

So 0xF0000000 has type uint.

```
decimal x = 0xF00000000;
```

Here x is a decimal variable. When you assign a uint value to it, that value is implicitly converted into a decimal (so it will fit into the decimal variable).